# Android BLE scan, SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED and getting hold of a BluetoothDevice instance

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Android app is for API Level 21 only and I'm testing it on a Nexus 5. It's a BLE central, connecting to a BLE peripheral which on which I control the firmware.

When first scanning for the device (peripheral) using startScan(), all is well. Supposing I then hold on to the BluetoothDevice instance passed to the ScanCallback. I can then call connectGatt() on it, discover services and read/write characteristics. So far, so good.

Now supposing the user navigates away, time passes and later they come back to the app and want to do something that requires a characteristic. I now have to step back and make sure I have a non-null instance of all of these things:

```
BluetoothLeScanner
BluetoothDevice
BluetoothGatt
BluetoothGattCharacteristic
```

At this point, my BluetoothDevice instance is null. No problem - I'll just scan again and get a new instance. Ah, but now I don't get ScanCallback.onScanResult() called at all - I get ScanCallback.onScanFailed() called with the error code

```
SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED
```

This is true, the BLE stack has remembered by previous scan and is refusing to duplicate it. But how do I now get hold of the BluetoothDevice instance from that scan? I see no way to do it in the Level 21 API.

Here's the complete code for my BLE service, which is used by various activities.

```
/* Copyright (C) Eliot Stock - All Rights Reserved
 * Unauthorized copying of this file, via any medium is strictly prohibited.
 * Proprietary and confidential.
 */
package com.eliotstock.bike.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.eliotstock.bike.ble.BleService;
import com.eliotstock.bike.ble.Characteristic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BleServiceForSoPost extends Service {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private String deviceMacAddress;

    private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
    private BluetoothDevice bleDevice;
    private BluetoothGatt bleGatt;

    private List<ScanFilter> scanFiltersFirstTime;
    private List<ScanFilter> scanFiltersReconnect;
    private ScanSettings scanSettingsLowPower;
    private ScanSettings scanSettingsLowLatency;

    private final IBinder binder = new BikeTrackerServiceBinder();

    private static final String PREF_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS = "pref_device_mac_address";

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic bikeTrackerTestMode;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic txPowerLevel;

    private IntentFilter bondStateChangedFilter =
            new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);

    private enum Action {
        NONE,
        READ_TEST_MODE,
        WRITE_TEST_MODE
    }

    private Action action;
    private Object actionValue;
    private Boolean stopScanInProgress = false;

    public class BikeTrackerServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public BleServiceForSoPost getService() {
            return BleServiceForSoPost.this;
        }
    }

    public BleServiceForSoPost() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Constructor " + this.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() " + this.hashCode());

        action = Action.NONE;
        actionValue = null;

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                getApplicationContext());
        deviceMacAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS, null);

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            enableBtIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            return;
        }

        bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        Log.d(TAG, "Bonded devices (whether connected or not):");
        for (BluetoothDevice device : bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "* " + device.getName() + " (" + device.getAddress() + ")");
        }

        ScanFilter scanFilterFirstTime = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setDeviceName("Bike")
                .build();
        scanFiltersFirstTime = new ArrayList<>();
        scanFiltersFirstTime.add(scanFilterFirstTime);

        ScanFilter scanFilterReconnect = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setDeviceAddress(deviceMacAddress)
                .build();
        scanFiltersReconnect = new ArrayList<>();
        scanFiltersReconnect.add(scanFilterReconnect);

        scanSettingsLowPower = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                .build();

        scanSettingsLowLatency = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // High power for first scan only.
                .build();

        if (deviceMacAddress == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "We do NOT know our device MAC address. Not scanning until prompted by" +
                    " user.");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "We know our device MAC address. Scanning only for it.");

            bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFiltersReconnect, scanSettingsLowPower, scanCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() " + this.hashCode());

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind() " + this.hashCode());

        return binder;
    }

    public void scanAndBindToNearestDevice() {
        if (deviceMacAddress != null) {
            return;
        }

        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFiltersFirstTime, scanSettingsLowLatency, scanCallback);
    }

    public void forgetDevice() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS, deviceMacAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy() " + this.hashCode());

        if (bleGatt == null) {
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Closing BluetoothGatt instance.");
        bleGatt.close();
        bleGatt = null;
    }

    public void readTestMode() {
        action = Action.READ_TEST_MODE;

        reconnect();

        if (bikeTrackerTestMode == null) {
            Log.e(TAG,  "Trying to read test mode before we have a characteristic instance" +
                    " for it.");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Reading characteristic for test mode.");

        // Calls back to onCharacteristicRead(), which in turns calls back to
        // SettingsActivity.setTestMode().
        if (!bleGatt.readCharacteristic(bikeTrackerTestMode)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't read test mode. BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic() returned false.");
        }
    }

    public void writeTestMode(Integer value) {
        action = Action.WRITE_TEST_MODE;
        actionValue = value;

        reconnect();

        if (bikeTrackerTestMode == null) {
            Log.e(TAG,  "Trying to write test mode before we have a characteristic instance" +
                    " for it.");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Writing characteristic for test mode.");

        bikeTrackerTestMode.setValue(value, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);

        if (!bleGatt.writeCharacteristic(bikeTrackerTestMode)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't write test mode. BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic() returned false.");
        }
    }

    public Boolean isDeviceConnected() {
        return (bleDevice != null && bleGatt != null && bikeTrackerTestMode != null);
    }

    // Check for null BLE Device, BLE GATT and BLE Characteristics, in that order, doing any
    // scanning, connecting or bonding required to get back to a state where all three are
    // available and we're bonded.
    private void reconnect() {
        if (bluetoothLeScanner == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "No BLE scanner instance available, probably because Bluetooth is turned" +
                    " off. Bailing out. Can't reconnect.");
            return;
        }

        if (bleDevice == null) {
            bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFiltersFirstTime, scanSettingsLowLatency, scanCallback);
            return;
        }

        if (bleGatt == null) {
            bleDevice.connectGatt(BleServiceForSoPost.this, true, gattCallback);
            return;
        }

        if (anyCharacteristicsAreNull()) {
            if (!bleGatt.discoverServices()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start discovering services."
                        + " BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() returned false. If this follows"
                        + " the status 133 problem with onConnectionStateChange(), reboot.");
            }
            return;
        }

        if (bleDevice.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            registerReceiver(bleBroadcastReceiver, bondStateChangedFilter);

            if (!bleDevice.createBond()) {
                Log.e(TAG,  "Can't create bond. BluetoothDevice.createBond() returned false.");
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Falling out of reconnect(). BLE device, GATT and characteristics are all ready"
                + " and we're bonded.");
    }

    private final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                onScanResult(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES, result);
            }
        }

        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Advertisement: Device name: " + result.getDevice().getName()
                    + ", address: " + result.getDevice().getAddress()
                    + ", RSSI: " + result.getRssi());

            switch (result.getDevice().getBondState()) {
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bond state: BOND_NONE");
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bond state: BOND_BONDING");
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bond state: BOND_BONDED");
                    break;
            }

            if (stopScanInProgress) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Dropping onScanResult() call while we're in the process of stopping"
                        + " scanning.");
                return;
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Found device. Stopping scanning.");
                stopScanInProgress = true;
            }

            bleDevice = result.getDevice();
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);

            if (deviceMacAddress != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "This is a reconnection. We already know our device's MAC address.");

                if (!result.getDevice().getAddress().equals(deviceMacAddress)) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "We scanned for a known device MAC address (" + deviceMacAddress
                            + ") but got a scan result for a different one ("
                            + result.getDevice().getAddress() + "). This should never happen.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This is a first connection. Storing device MAC address as shared"
                        + " preference.");

                deviceMacAddress = result.getDevice().getAddress();             
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(PREF_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS, deviceMacAddress);

                editor.apply();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to GATT server.");

            stopScanInProgress = false;

            if (bleDevice == null) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "BLE Device is null in main looper thread."
                        + " Why? We should be calling connectGatt() now but can't.");
                return;
            }

            bleDevice.connectGatt(BleServiceForSoPost.this, true, gattCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Scan failed.");

            switch (errorCode) {
                case SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED:
                    Log.w(TAG, "Reason: 'Fails to start scan as BLE scan with the same settings" +
                            " is already started by the app.' Resuming reconnection from after" +
                            " scan. BLE device: " + bleDevice + ", BLE GATT: " + bleGatt);
                    break;
                case SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED:
                    Log.w(TAG, "Reason: 'Fails to start scan as app cannot be registered.'");
                    break;
                case SCAN_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED:
                    Log.w(TAG, "Reason: 'Fails to start power optimized scan as this feature is not"
                            + " supported.'");
                    break;
                case SCAN_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                    Log.w(TAG, "Reason: 'Fails to start scan due to an internal error.'");
                    break;
            }

            bleDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange()");

            switch (status) {
                case BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: GATT_SUCCESS");
                    break;
                case BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: GATT_FAILURE");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: 8. Normal if caused by peers moving apart.");
                    break;
                case 22:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: 22. Don't know what this is but have seen it before.");
                    break;
                case 34:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: 34. Don't know what this is but have seen it before.");
                    break;
                case 133:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Status 133. This may mean the connection was lost because the"
                            + " remote device dropped it. See Android 4.4 bug.");
                    gatt.close();
                    gatt.connect();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognised status: " + status);
            }

            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "New state: STATE_CONNECTED");           
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "New state: STATE_CONNECTING");              
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "New state: STATE_DISCONNECTED");            
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "New state: STATE_DISCONNECTING");           
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognised new state: " + newState);                  
            }

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTED to GATT server. Starting service discovery.");

                bleGatt = gatt;

                if (!gatt.discoverServices()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start discovering services."
                            + " BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() returned false. If this follows"
                            + " the status 133 problem with onConnectionStateChange(), reboot.");
                }
            }
            else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "DISCONNECTED from GATT server.");

                if (bleGatt != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Closing BluetoothGatt instance.");
                    bleGatt.close();
                }

                bleGatt = null;
                bleDevice = null;
                txPowerLevel = null;

                if (deviceMacAddress == null) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "We've become disconnected but don't yet know our device MAC"
                            + " address, which should be impossible.");
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting half a second...");

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Starting scanning at low power, looking only for our known" +
                                " device.");

                        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFiltersReconnect, scanSettingsLowPower,
                                scanCallback);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Discovered services:");

                for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gatt.getServices()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*" + BleService.toDebugString(gattService));

                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic c : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "**" + Characteristic.toDebugString(c));

                        if (Characteristic.BIKE_TRACKER_TEST_MODE_ID.equals(c.getUuid())) {
                            bikeTrackerTestMode = c;
                        }

                        if (Characteristic.TX_POWER_LEVEL.equals(c.getUuid())) {
                            txPowerLevel = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (status == 129) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR");

                bikeTrackerTestMode = null;
                txPowerLevel = null;
            }
            else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received non-GATT_SUCCESS status: " + status);

                bikeTrackerTestMode = null;
                txPowerLevel = null;
            }

            if (bleDevice == null) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "BluetoothDevice instance is null at service discovery. How did we"
                        + " get this far? Using the one on this GATT instance.");
                bleDevice = gatt.getDevice();
            }

            if (BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE == bleDevice.getBondState()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Not yet bonded. Creating bond now.");

                registerReceiver(bleBroadcastReceiver, bondStateChangedFilter);

                if (!bleDevice.createBond()) {
                    Log.e(TAG,  "Can't create bond. BluetoothDevice.createBond() returned false.");
                }

                return;
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Bonded (or bonding) already. Good.");
            }

            if (bleGatt == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "We have no BluetoothGatt instance and should do by now. Bailing out of"
                        + " doing anything with Characteristics.");
                return;
            }

            if (action == Action.READ_TEST_MODE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Reading characteristic for test Mode.");

                if (!bleGatt.readCharacteristic(bikeTrackerTestMode)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Can't read test mode. BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()" +
                            " returned false.");
                }
            }

            if (action == Action.WRITE_TEST_MODE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Writing characteristic for test mode.");

                Integer value = (Integer)actionValue;
                bikeTrackerTestMode.setValue(value, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);

                if (!bleGatt.writeCharacteristic(bikeTrackerTestMode)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Can't write test mode. BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()" +
                            " returned false.");
                }

                actionValue = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic c,
                int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead(): " + Characteristic.toDebugString(c));

            onCharacteristicReadOrChanged(c, status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged(): " + Characteristic.toDebugString(c));

            onCharacteristicReadOrChanged(c, 0);
        }

        private void onCharacteristicReadOrChanged(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Got GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION status. Are we bonded?");
                return;
            }
            else if (status == 132) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Got non-GATT_SUCCESS status of 132. All bets off below.");
            }
            else if (status == 133) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Got non-GATT_SUCCESS status of 133. All bets off below.");
            }
            else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Got non-GATT_SUCCESS status of " + status + ". All bets off below.");
            }

            if (bikeTrackerTestMode.equals(c)) {
                try {
                    Integer testModeInt = c.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,
                            0);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Bike Tracker test mode: " + testModeInt);
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Can't really read test mode characteristic. Value is null.");
                }
            }
            else if (txPowerLevel.equals(c)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tx Power Level: " + new String(c.getValue()));
            }
            else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unrecognised characteristic read or changed: " + c);
            }

            action = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic c,
                int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite(): " + Characteristic.toDebugString(c));

            if (BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS == status) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Success");
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error writing characteristic. Status: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver bleBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(): " + intent.getAction());

            if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);
                final int previousBondState =
                        intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1);

                if (previousBondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
                        && bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bonded. Unregistering broadcast receiver.");
                    unregisterReceiver(this);

                    if (bleGatt == null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Can't read sensitivity. BluetoothGatt is still null.");
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading characteristic for test mode.");

                    if (!bleGatt.readCharacteristic(bikeTrackerTestMode)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Can't read test mode. BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()" +
                                " returned false.");
                    }
                }
                else if (previousBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
                        && bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unbonded.");
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ignoring BLE irrelevant broadcast intent: " + intent.getAction());
            }
        }
    };

    private Boolean anyCharacteristicsAreNull() {
        if (bikeTrackerTestMode == null
            || txPowerLevel == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I should mention that my BluetoothGatt instance is also null, so there's no skipping the BluetoothDevice.connectGatt() call and going straight to the BluetoothGatt.discoverServices().

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: A fair comment. Have added complete code.

Comment: Have now opened an AOSP bug for this here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172541

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for BLE scan's SCAN\_FAILED\_APPLICATION\_REGISTRATION\_FAILED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516399/solution-for-ble-scans-scan-failed-application-registration-failed)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
```

change to

```
bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(this);
```

Comment: That's valid, but I'm still getting SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED for a scan that I've supposedly stopped with stopScan().

Comment: This is a pretty old thread. I would assume the Android BLE library has been improved since then.

Comment: I think the Android BLE stack still works pretty much like this. If you read the source for the top of the stack, it treats the identity of the scan callback passed in as the identity of the scan. So, if two ScanCallback instances that are equals() to one another are passed in but not the same instance, you'll get this behaviour. If they're actually the same instance, you'll get this behaviour. If they do not equals() one another, you won't.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is four years old. Android BLE has changed a lot since then.

Comment: I see - yeah I bumped this because I'm having the same issue on Android 6 whereby every time I startScan() after stopScan() I get SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED. 
But if I understand what you're saying correctly @Eliot if I instantiate a new ScanCallback instance every time I startScan(), that should solve it...

Comment: Can confirm that redefining the ScanCallback each time works, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue onScanFailed with error code 1(Already Started) in Google Pixel.  I tried all the possible solution like restarting device , Programmatically stop scan , etc..And nothing helped in my case.
Workaround :
Download any bluetooth finder or scanner app from playstore and try scanning. Now try with your app. This got my app scanning successfully.