# CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan failed: app cannot be registered (Alt-Beacon Library)

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I am using Alt-Beacon Library, and getting this error and unable to detect beacons,

> CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan failed: app cannot be registered

Platform: OnePlus5 Android 7.1.1

Could anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for BLE scan's SCAN\_FAILED\_APPLICATION\_REGISTRATION\_FAILED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516399/solution-for-ble-scans-scan-failed-application-registration-failed)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, this appears to be an internal error in Android, indicating something is wrong with the bluetooth stack.  One option is to turn bluetooth off and back on again to try to clear the condition (you could even do so programmatically as described in this related answer:

[How to fix Android BLE SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376682/how-to-fix-android-ble-scan-failed-application-registration-failed-error)

However, as that answer shows, this may not always work.  Sorry, I know this is not a great answer.  I'd love to hear if somebody has a better one.

Comment: Why does this error happen on Android 8? I get it as well. Does that mean that monitoring will fail subsequently when this occurs? Why is the Lollipop scanner active anyways? Shouldn't that be the new Android O scanner?

Comment: This error means the Bluetooth stack is not operating normally.  This is regardless of Android OS version.

Comment: The cause for this seems to be a lot of started (and never stopped) scans. If the number of maximum scans of the device is reached and we try to start another one, then this error occurs. Unfortunately there is no way to stop all scans of your app.
A scan can only be stopped using the ScanCallback object or PendingIntent object used to start it. But if these objects are gone (i.e. because the app was killed), there is no way to stop the scan.

Comment: @rickul 
So, if we turn on and off the Bluetooth as david suggested, we just stop all the scans, but manually?