# SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED issue in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating app that communicates with a BLE device which is advertising packets.  We're able to connect to and catch most of the packets, but occasionally, after a few uses and open/closes of the app, I begin to get a SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED [0x02] error when connecting to the bluetooth provided in the phone.

I've seen this in 2 different devices so far, but the only resolution I've found is to reboot the phone.

Has anyone else seen this issue or had any success with a fix or workaround?

Comment: Are you properly closing all BluetoothGatt objects when you are done with them? Are you stopping all scans when you don't need to scan anymore?

Comment: @Emil  That's a good suggestion.  I did some research and found that there is a limited pool of Gatt objects.  I've updated the code grab them using a singleton pattern to reduce the creation/reference holding, and I thing this has solved the issue on my current two devices.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for BLE scan's SCAN\_FAILED\_APPLICATION\_REGISTRATION\_FAILED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516399/solution-for-ble-scans-scan-failed-application-registration-failed)