# How to solve SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-12

I am trying to perform BLE scans in a foreground service (Android 12) after some start scan end stop scan I receive the error `SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED`, I cannot figure out what is the reason of the error.

I do startScan and stopScan in sequence (the scan is a long-running scan)

The app target SDK 32 so I have the new Bluetooth permissions.

This is the complete scenario:

1. I open the app and I start the foreground service
2. I close the application (the foreground service is still running)
3. The foreground service scan and connect to my device and then I stop scanning
4. I turn off my BLE device and the foreground service start to scan again
5. I turn on my ble device and the foreground service detect it and connect to it.
6. Repeat step 4 and suddenly the error `SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED` show.

I also notice this error in the logcat `App 'com.sample.xxx' is scanning too much clientif` (I look into AOSP source code and seems that this string is specific of Xiaomi ROM)

https://github.com/appersiano/TestingBackgroundConnection

P.S. Tested on Xiaomi Mi11 Lite 5g

How can I solve?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more information. What does your manifest look like? have you declared the right permissions?

Comment: This might also be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516399/solution-for-ble-scans-scan-failed-application-registration-failed

Comment: Do you properly `.close()` all your `BluetoothGatt` objects when you're done with them? Otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: yes,  `.disconnect` and `.close` when  `onConnectionStateChange` I get a disconnection

Comment: Maybe you can show your full code?

Comment: @Emil I have uploaded the code on a public repo

Comment: Did you try if this happens on other phone models?

Comment: Yes, also on other phones I have the same problem, after a while the error appear

Answer (score 1):

**you should not scan more than 5 times in 30s.**

GattService:
This constant defines the time window an app can scan multiple times.
Any single app can scan up to |NUM_SCAN_DURATIONS_KEPT| times during
this window.
Once they reach this limit, they must wait until their earliest recorded scan exits this window.

```
static final int NUM_SCAN_DURATIONS_KEPT = 5;
static final long EXCESSIVE_SCANNING_PERIOD_MS = 30 * 1000;
```

Comment: I know about this limit and when I reach it I have an error on logcat, but my problem is different